# How to get Markdown gem to not render comments into the generated HTML?

Tags: ruby, markdown

I have the following Ruby code processing a Markdown file:

```
html = Markdown.new(markdownContents).to_html
```

The result of this includes a comment block at the top of the file, which I would like it *not* to do, but I can't seem to find an option in the documentation to *not* render this comment block.

```
<!-- === begin markdown block =====================================================
   generated by markdown 1.0.0 on Ruby 1.9.3 (2012-04-20) [i386-mingw32]
        on 2012-08-15 15:34:51 -0400 with Markdown engine kramdown (0.13.7)
          using options { !to be done! }
-->
```

Is there an option for this, or would I have to submit a pull request? ;)

Answer (score 0):

The code to add this header seems to have been added in [this commit](https://github.com/geraldb/markdown/commit/ff7c8d503471c535b686a65dfc5101800b60e89b) and only applies to the kramdown engine. It seems the solutions are:

- to submit a pull request with code to make this optional
- configure `Markdown` to use a different engine. Details [here](http://geraldb.github.com/markdown/) in the **Markdown Engine Loading Order** section